# Is there a way to update frame size with Lua?

Tags: lua, game-physics, roblox

So basically, there is a problem with my GUI. It is supposed to contract when told so, but for some reason, I can't get it to do that.

I have tried looking into the size settings, then into connection within this and remote events. I didn't find a problem with server for it either.
Am I doing something wrong? And if so, is there another way arround? Or is it just an error of the compiler?

I used "StaminaUpdate" and "Sprinting" for the remote event names.
Here is the code for the Client and Server:

````
local userInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local replicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local players = game:GetService("Players")

-- input true
userInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift then
        replicatedStorage.Events.Sprinting:FireServer("True")
    end
end)

-- input false
userInputService.InputEnded:Connect(function(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift then
        replicatedStorage.Events.Sprinting:FireServer("False")
    end
end)

-- GUI update
replicatedStorage.Events.StaminaUpdate.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(stamina, maxStamina)
    players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.Stamina.Bar.Size = UDim2.new(0, (maxStamina - stamina) * .2, 0, 17)
end)

-- Below is the server code

-- locals
local replicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local players = game:GetService("Players")
local RunService = game:GetService("RunService")

local maxStamina = 500
local staminaRegen = 5

local sprintingModifier = 1.8
local sprintingCost = 10

local sprintingPlayer = {}


players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local stamina = Instance.new("IntValue", player)
    stamina.Value = maxStamina
    stamina.Name = "Stamina"
    
    stamina.Changed:Connect(function(property)
        replicatedStorage.Events.StaminaUpdate:FireClient(player, stamina.Value, maxStamina)
    end)
end)

-- input = false or true
replicatedStorage.Events.Sprinting.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, state)
    local humanoid = player.Character.Humanoid
    
    if state == "True" and humanoid:GetState() == Enum.HumanoidStateType.RunningNoPhysics and humanoid.MoveDirection.Magnitude > 0 then
        sprintingPlayer[player.Name] = humanoid.WalkSpeed
        humanoid.WalkSpeed = humanoid.WalkSpeed * sprintingModifier
    elseif state == "False" and sprintingPlayer[player.Name] then
        humanoid.WalkSpeed = sprintingPlayer[player.name]
        sprintingPlayer[player.Name] = nil
    end
end)

-- adjusting stamina 
RunService.Heartbeat:Connect(function()
    for index, player in pairs{players:GetCHuldren()} do
        local stamina = player.Stamina
        local name = player.Name
        
        if not sprintingPlayer[name] then
            if stamina.Value > maxStamina then 
                stamina.Value = maxStamina
            elseif stamina.Value < maxStamina then
                stamina.Value = stamina.Value + staminaRegen
            end
        else
            if stamina.Value >= sprintingCost then
                stamina.Value = stamina.Value - sprintingCost
            else
                player.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = sprintingPlayer[name]
                sprintingPlayer[name] = nil
            end
        end
    end
end)```
````

Comment: Is this about some game or something? Because it sounds like it is

Comment: Yep, it is about a game.

Comment: Please add a tag for the game/framework/library you're using. With only the "lua" tag, you're attracting people who know vanilla Lua, but not about most of the functions you're calling in that code.

Comment: Is the gui size updating at all? Or is it that it's not updating three way you expect? When you are setting the size of the gui, why are you multiplying the calculated value by 0.2? `UDim2.new(0, (maxStamina - stamina) * .2, 0, 17)` Won't that mean that the frame size will at most be only 20% of the parent container's size?